Uniform Convergence to non-holomorphic function
I've been tasked to answer whether the following is true or false:
Suppose that $f_n$ form a sequence of holomorphic functions on the unit disk. Then it cannot be that $f_n \rightrightarrows |z|^2$ on any open subset of the unit disk.
I claim this is false:
Suppose otherwise, then there is some open subset $U \subseteq D(0,1)$ such that $f_n \rightrightarrows |z|^2$ on $U$ and hence on any compact subset of $U$. Then from a classical theorem in complex analysis (Krantz, Function Theory of One Complex Variable, 3.5.1 for instance), we must have that $|z|^2 = z \bar z$ is holomorphic on $U$ which is impossible since $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} z\bar z\neq 0$ on any nonzero point of $U$.
My only doubt is whether there is some gap in my line of reasoning (perhaps a counterexample that I have not considered)?

What does $\rightrightarrows$ mean?

Uniform convergence

No need for fancy theorems. A little grind shows that $\int_\gamma |z|^2 dz = 2 \pi i r z_0$, where $\gamma(t) = z_0 + re^{it}$. In particular, if $r>0$ and $z_0 \ne 0$, the integral is non zero. If $f_n \to f$ uniformly on any open subset of the unit disk that we see that $\int_\gamma f_n dz =0 \to \int_\gamma f dz$ and so $\int_\gamma f dz = 0$. By choosing $z_0,r$ appropriately we see that $f_n$ cannot converge uniformly to $z \mapsto |z|^2$on any open subset of the unit disk.
